# Issue with Subquerying

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

for an assignment I have to add three columns of a table (Basic, Additional Labour and Additional Parts) to make an overall charge. I then also have to determine the minimum and maximum overall charge found as well as the average. I have been successful in writing an Overall Charge query

```
SELECT Service.ServiceId, Sum([BasicCharges]+[AdditionalLabourCharges]+
    [AdditionalPartCharges]) AS [OverallCharge] 
FROM Service
```

However, I cannot get my head around adding these min, max and avg statements into this. My draft looks like... but does not work

```
SELECT  MIN(OverallCharge) AS [MinOverallCharge], 
    MAX(OverallCharge) AS [MaxOverallCharge], 
    AVG(OverallCharge) AS [AverageOverallCharge]
FROM Service
WHERE Service
(SELECT Sum([S.BasicCharges]+[S.AdditionalLabourCharges]+[S.AdditionalPartCharges]) AS [OverallCharge]
FROM Service AS S);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Nic

Comment: Do you want to get these values for each service?

Comment: No Alireza, meaning what was the minimum overall found and what was the maximum, as well as the average of all the overalls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  MIN(OverallCharge) AS [MinOverallCharge], 
    MAX(OverallCharge) AS [MaxOverallCharge], 
    AVG(OverallCharge) AS [AverageOverallCharge]
FROM 
    (SELECT ServiceId, Sum([S.BasicCharges]+[S.AdditionalLabourCharges]+
    [S.AdditionalPartCharges]) AS [OverallCharge]
    FROM Service AS S
    GROUP BY ServiceId) dt;
```

The subquery generates a table which contains `OverallCharge` for each `ServiceId`, then the main query gets your `min`, `max`, `avg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT --get the min/avg/max of all charges
   MIN(OverallCharge) AS [MinOverallCharge], 
   MAX(OverallCharge) AS [MaxOverallCharge], 
   AVG(OverallCharge) AS [AverageOverallCharge]
FROM 
 ( -- calculate OverallCharge for each ServiceId
   SELECT S.ServiceId, 
      Sum([S.BasicCharges]+[S.AdditionalLabourCharges]+[S.AdditionalPartCharges]) AS [OverallCharge]
   FROM Service AS S
   GROUP BY S.ServiceId
 ) dt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However, its wanting me to enter a parameter value for Service ? What should I do?

Comment: You probably need to use the alias **S** instead of **Service** in the select. Modified my answer

Comment: Now its saying my query doesnt include SErviceId as an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a subquery would do the trick. Use your first query to get the sum per row. Then you can calculate the AVG, MIN and MAX:

```
SELECT
    MIN(subquery.OverallCharge) AS [MinOverallCharge], 
    MAX(subquery.OverallCharge) AS [MaxOverallCharge], 
    AVG(subquery.OverallCharge) AS [AverageOverallCharge]
FROM
(
    SELECT ([S.BasicCharges]+[S.AdditionalLabourCharges]+[S.AdditionalPartCharges])
        AS [OverallCharge]
    FROM Service AS S
) subquery;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but that just adds up all the overallcharge values ($1480). i need to find what the minimum overall found and what was the maximum, as well as the average of all the overalls...

Comment: Jep, of course it does, I edited my answer. The results of the subquery are not supposed to be summed. Try again?